# FULL OUTER JOIN returns NULL values from foreign keys table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, join, outer-join

I'm working on a Database called "ExaminationDB_Test". The goal is to Manage Student Exam Data. But, Before we go to the Examination System we need to manage the basic data of Student e.g Class, Section, Group etc.

I have made following Tables:

- Student (Contains Student Data)
- Class (Contains Classes)
- Groups (Contains Groups)
- Sections (Contains Sections)
- PrimaryData (Contains Foreign Keys to all these Tables)

Here are Tables Designs:

**Student:**

[image: Student Table Design]

**Class:**

[image: Class Table Design]

**Group**

[image: Group Table Design]

**Sections**

[image: Section Table Design]

**Primary Data:**

[image: Primary Data Table Design]

And the Data in these Tables:

**Student:**

[image: Student Table Data]

**Class:**

[image: Class Table Data]

**Groups:**

[image: Groups Table Data]

**Sections:**

[image: Sections Table Data]

**PrimaryData:** (It's Empty because these are all Foreign Keys to above Tables!)

[image: PrimaryData Table Data]

**Database Diagram:**

[image: Database Diagram]

The Goal here is to Select All the Data of **Student** using **Student Roll No**.
I have Tried the Following Queries for it:

```
SELECT * FROM Student Full Outer Join PrimaryData ON PrimaryData.StuID=Student.StuRollNo where Student.StuRollNo='1001';
SELECT * FROM Student Join PrimaryData ON PrimaryData.StuID=Student.StuRollNo where Student.StuRollNo='1001';
```

Here's what it Returns:
[image: Query Result]

The Output must have Group Name, Class Name and Section Name in it!

> I have tried most of the Solutions Available on StackOverflow regarding **JOINS**
>   But this result always has been the same.

Please help me fix this Issue!

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please read the accepted answer of ["Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) and [edit] your question to include proper sample data, your current attempt and your desired results.

Comment: PrimaryData table is mapping table between student and section, class and group based on your ERD. How do you expect section, class and group data for student without having data in primarydata?

Comment: @ASP What data should be in Primary Data?

Comment: You need to create an row like (1001,FSC1,1001,Engg)

Comment: @ASP This means I'll have to create rows for all records?

Comment: Yes, all student should have this mapping data.

Comment: @ASP It Returns ID's why not Names? I mean Why Primary keys and no Data against those Primary keys?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170590/discussion-between-asp-and-zaryab-waseem).

Comment: I don't think you have data in PrimaryData Table. Full Outer Join yelds NULL if Right Table doesn't have data.

Comment: @SameerMahat I have added the data now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PrimaryData table is mapping table between student and section, class and group based on your ERD.  How do you expect section, class and group data for student without having data in primarydata?

insert record to primarydata table. this will work for you.

```
insert into primarydata values (1001,'FSC1',1001,'Engg')
```

After adding this entry then modify your query and add section, class and group master tables to get names.

Comment: How to retrieve the data that is against those IDs (Primary Keys) instead of IDs themselves?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM Student cross Join PrimaryData ON PrimaryData.StuID=Student.StuRollNo  where Student.StuRollNo='1001';

select E.* 
FROM   Student E
       CROSS JOIN PrimaryData P
WHERE  P.StuID = E.StuRollNo  
and E.StuRollNo = '1001'
```

Since there is no matching between columns , try to use a explicit join like left outer join.

Comment: Still Same Result!!

Comment: Still you have no data on primaryData table it will return null, the best fix is  joining other tables directly with  explicity join statments

Answer (score 0):

I see that StuRollNo is int but you put '1001' as string.